# Call view method from an activity in non-activity class

Tags: java, android

**This is my method in CheckActivity.java**

```
public void check5(View view) {
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    modelItems[5] = new Model("Item", 1);
    CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, modelItems);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

**This how I call method in non-activity class**

```
CheckActivity mActivity = new CheckActivity();
mActivity.check5();
```

But this is the error I got.

[image]

I alt-entered and android studio create new method in CheckActivity.java

[image]

```
public void check5()
{
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    modelItems[5] = new Model("Item", 1);
    CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, modelItems);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

But my code will not work with `(View view)` how do I fix that?

Edit - Some told me that this is bad idea to do. So if this is impossible how do I copy my method into non-activity class?

Comment: If you come across this behavior where you call Activity method from non-activity class I think its bed design and practice. Activity methods in most cases should server Activity only.

Comment: You should not instantiate an activity, instead create a callback method and you are not using the view within the parameters, so you coul technically pass null

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `Context` of `CheckActivity` `Activity` in your non Activity Class and then you call `Activity` method from Non `Activity` Class by casting `Context` in `Activity` name.

```
((CheckActivity)context).check5(view);
```

pass view with just like you have called member function , so you can access variables of class `CheckActvity` declared as `public` .

Comment: But the OP wants to pass View as the parameter to `check5()` method.

Comment: @Shashanth TechticalBecaon has view in non Activity Class or it should take like method calling of non Activity class.